# how can one deploy/install "Shadowolf"?

Tags: java, bittorrent, tomcat

[This](http://code.google.com/p/shadowolf/) is the project that I am talking about. However, there is no mention of the way that it can be installed.

I have installed **Tomcat**. I have also *svn*-checked out the src code with:

`svn checkout http://shadowolf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ shadowolf-read-only`

After a bit of looking around, I decided to run **ant**. After satisfying the **Ivy** library dependancy - the project was built. But, the resulting file is a **.jar**? How am I supposed to run that with **Tomcat**? Or was it supposed to be built some other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the .jar file with the command

```
java -jar PACKAGENAME.jar
```

Comment: then where does the Tomcat/Jetty part come in?

Answer (score 0):

The main class is not specified in the MANIFEST of the jar file, therefore the variant with *java -jar Shadowolf-1.0-prealpha.jar* will not work. Try this one:

```
java -cp Shadowolf-1.0-prealpha.jar com.shadowolf.Shadowolf
```

For further question I would contact one of the members of the project.